# make two parallel ajax calls with tokeninput

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-tokeninput

I have been experimenting with `tokeninput` . It works like a charm . But recently i stumbled upon a requirement which is to make two ajax calls on the same the input bar .

**Scenario :**  My input bar

```
<input id="autocompleteMe" >
```

i intialize the `tokeninput` plugin by :

```
$("#autocompleteMe").tokeninput(
"mysite/LookUp.php?callFrom=FromFile",
{
 theme : "facebook",
 propertyToSearch : "myProp"
}
);
```

This works fine & gets the result and populates my dropdown with results .

**Requirement** :
This result is from a file on my Server . If the result is found/not found (in both cases) i need to look for the same input in my DB also , and provide the suggestions . Since the DB might have got updated .

i.e. on the user input two ajax call should be fired which are :

1. Get Results from the File (Which i want to bind as soon as the
   results are returned )
2. Get Results from DB also ( which may take
   time . and will be appended in the dropdown as soon as they are
   retrieved ).

**What i thought** :

```
$("#autocompleteMe").tokeninput(
"mysite/LookUp.php?callFrom=FromFile",
{
 theme : "facebook",
 propertyToSearch : "myProp",
 onResult : function(result){
  // bind the returned results here to the dropdown . Since they are from the file 
  // but how ?

  $.getJSON("mysite/LookUp.php",{callFrom : "DBCall"},function(DBResponse){
   // append the results to the dropdown .
   // also this will a async call . i will have attach the callback . I have no idea how to 
  });
 }
}
);
```

Apologies for such a dumb question . But i am banging my head since long on this problem.
Any help will be obliged .

Thanks & Regards!

Comment: Is this just an issue of asynchronous call or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path...

Your onResult block should look something like this, if I am not mistaken

```
onResult : function(firstResultSet){
  var returningResults;
  $.getJSON("mysite/LookUp.php",{callFrom : "DBCall", firstResultSet: firstResultSet},function(DBResponse){
       returningResults = DBResponse;
   });
   return returningResults; 
}
```

Point is, you do whatever you want inside of **onResult** callback, and after you manipulated your data, you **return** it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see you were making the exact same call twice... There is no need for it, just wanted to include it so you can get a hang of which variable has what stored inside...

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response ! But i don't get the logic of sending the "firstResultSet" to my DB Call logic ? .
Also according to your logic (if i am not mistaken ) the user will have to wait till the data is fetched from DB (which will be a lag) . What i wanted is to show the "firstResultSet" till the result is being fetched in the back end by the DBCall .

Do correct me if wrong .

Comment: Yes, it will have to wait and produce a lag... but in my opinion, you are making a wrong approach here. First, if a user searches for something, and there are not enough results (your logic decides that it should look into database), user will not be aware of this. This is bad practice, as user could get very confused on how your input suggestions work. Asynchronous call is your best bet. Your second best bet is making the one backend call which returns results from both sources...

Comment: I understand @kosturko , but since the File Data has the Top Searches i would always like to display the data from there and meanwhile fetch other records too from the DB (of course both the results will be separated by a "list divider" , hence making the user aware of what data is what and from where) . 

Also the data fetch from the DB is irrespective of the presence in the File . As i mentioned that even if the matching results were found from the File, the logic will still hit DB (or better the cached result from DB) to show both results (divided by a marker or a divider ).